# How to describe arbitrary directed graph if I have a set?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, order-theory

I have an arbitrary set $A$ which is a subset of another set $A \subset B$, the elements of the set $A$ constitue a directed graph. If I want to describe it via notation (algebra) without mentioning the concrete elements, how can I do that? Is that even possible?

Comment: Notation (not at all the same thing as algebra) is just a way of conveying information. What information exactly do you want to convey?

Comment: I want to convey that the set $A$'s elements all from a directed graph i.e. a path.

Comment: You might be confused; there are directed graphs other than paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notation for the statement "something is a directed graph". This is probably because it's hard to imagine a situation where you have an object, but you're not sure if it's a directed graph or not. (There is no larger class of objects, some of which are directed graphs and some of which are not, such that you want to say "that object in the larger class? it's actually a directed graph".)

You can use notation for the other relationship in your problem. For example, if you have a directed graph $D$, you could write $V(D) \subseteq B$ to indicate that the vertices of $D$ are a subset of $B$, or $E(D) \subseteq B$ to indicate that the edges of $D$ are a subset of $B$.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little what you meant by `it's hard to imagine a situation where you have an object, but you're not sure if it's a directed graph or not.` in this case I am sure that an object is a path.

Comment: What sort of thing would it have been, if it weren't a path?

Comment: I dont have a directed graph as a notation, I only have a set as a notation, whose elements form a path. Are you implying that there is no notation for this exact situation? I have to explicitly mention the directed graph as the main object and implicitly define its vertices as a subset $V(D) \subseteq B$? Instead of otherway round of explicitly defining a set?

Comment: I also want to ask: what do you mean by "its elements form a path"? A directed graph has two pieces: the vertices and the edges. Which ones are the elements of $A$? (And whichever it is, where are you getting the other piece from?)

Comment: I understood what was the issue in my understanding. I just considered nodes in set $A$ but to form a path I need edges as well to be part of the set! So my set containes only one object that is the nodes. So having nodes alone will be meaningless, I have to declare edges as well as part of elements of the set $A$, right?

Comment: having that said can I say that set $A$ consists of nodes of the graph, and these nodes form a path, but using notation?

Comment: Usually, you don't put vertices and edges in the same set together; they're different types of objects. (If the edges form a set $E$, you could maybe say $(A,E) \cong P_n$ to indicate that $(A,E)$ is a graph isomorphic to the path graph $P_n$, though I think this is a case where words are *better*.)

Comment: Thanks makes so much sense :) I can write graph $V(A,E)$ where nodes $V(A) \subset B$? This makes more sense to me, just wanna know if it is right?

Comment: The $V$ stands for "vertices", so $V(A,E)$ probably isn't the notation you're looking for; I justed $(A,E)$ but $G(A,E)$ might also be reasonable.